# Bash script won't work on current directory

Tags: shell, shell-script, directory, cd-command, pwd

I'm using Kali linux which is based on Debian and wrote an script to copy some files from where the script is based to a specified directory. But when I execute my script (called `CopyFiles.sh`), `cp` command works on the `root`, not current directory. Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cp -f * /var/www/
```

Also I tried `./*` but same error but if I change directory to my scripts (`cd` command) it works fine. I can use following script without problem but I don't want to use any additical commands and want to know why my script doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash

SCRIPT_DIR="$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")"
cp -f "$SCRIPT_DIR/"* /var/www/
```

Comment: Which one of these is correct? That you "wrote a script to copy some files from the current directory" or that you "wrote a script to copy some files from the directory where the script is"? They are not necessarily the same thing and I think that's where the confusion lies.

Comment: What happens when you try to run the original script? Do you get an error?

Comment: Do you have any filenames in the current directory that begin with `-`?

Comment: @roaima I want to copy files from "Where script is" not "where terminal is and not current directory". I think you can solve my problem :D

Comment: If you want to run from where the script is, you have to do the second way. Relative pathnames are always interpreted relative to your working directory, the directory containing the script is irrelevant.

Comment: @Barmar but why I can use first script on Backtrack (ubuntu-based) without problem? also can I count on second script? is that stable?

Comment: I don't know what Backtrack is, so I can't explain why it works there.

Comment: My guess is that `*` expands to directories too. Can you use something like `rsync` instead?

Comment: @Barmar ["Backtrack" is the previous generation of Kali.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22368470/1672723)

Comment: If you're just talking about Linux distros, then I doubt that it worked as you describe. This is how bash, and other similar shells, have always worked. It has never been the case that running a shell script changed directory to that of the script.

Answer (score 2):

The command `cp -f * /var/www/` copies files matching `*` in the caller's current directory, i.e. your current directory. It is irrelevant where the script is located.

Comment: So there is no method to do this without using second script? also is that script stable and won't make any problem later?

Comment: The script looks perfectly reasonable to me. It's not how I'd write it - personally I'd require the source directory as a command line argument rather than basing that on the location of the script. But your use case is presumably different to mine.

Comment: No you don't need a second script. Just put an command line argument in there like so `cd $1; cp -f * /var/www/` and when you execute the script just put the directory location in there `CopyFiles.sh path-of-direcory`

Comment: @Jeight in that case why not `cp -fp "$1"/* /var/www`